# How to use background color in printThis plugin?

Tags: html, javascript, jquery

It's not importing the background color to my printed page.

[image: My HTML page]

[image: My printed page]

```
    function printThis()
    {
          $("#printLayout").printThis({

            importCSS: false,

            importStyle: true,

            printContainer: true,

          });
    }
```